# Proof of a formula containing double factorial

Tags: power-series, special-functions

How can I prove the formula:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!!}=\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2/2}\left[2+\sqrt{2\pi}\operatorname{erf}\frac{x}{\sqrt\pi}\right]?$$
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe our definitions of the error function differ by a constant, but the following approach works anyway:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{x^k}{k!!}&=&\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{2^n n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}\\&=&e^{x^2/2}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}n!\\&=&e^{x^2/2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-z}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n x^{2n+1} z^n}{(2n+1)!}\,dz\\&=&e^{x^2/2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^{n+1} x^{2n+1} u^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\,du\\ &=&e^{x^2/2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sqrt{2}\,e^{-u^2}\sinh\left(\sqrt{2}\, u x\right)\,du\\&=&\color{red}{e^{x^2/2}+e^{x^2/2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\text{Erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Nicely done!  Interesting that the splitting of even and odd terms leads to a straightforward development.  +1

Comment: Very good. $erf$ is the error function not a constant.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: I know that. I am asserting that my $\text{Erf}$ is given by $$\text{Erf}(u)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{u}e^{-x^2}\,dx $$ while your definition has probably a different normalization constant.